# How can I flip the direction of curly braces in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using TikZ with the following code to draw a picture. How can I turn the curly bracket next to `$P_2$` to the right?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (-1,0) rectangle +(6,7.5);
\filldraw[thick, top color=white,bottom color=red!50!] (0.5,0) rectangle node{$N_S$} +(1.3,0.5);
\filldraw[thick, top color=white,bottom color=red!50!] (2.2,0) rectangle node{$N_L$} +(1.3,0.65);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,0.5) rectangle node{$P_{1}$} +(1.3,0.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,0.65) rectangle node{$P_{2}$} +(1.3,1.0);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,1.0) rectangle node{$P_{3}$} +(1.3,1.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,1.65) rectangle node{$P_{4}$} +(1.3,2.0);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,2.5) rectangle node{$P_{5}$} +(1.3,2.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,3.65) rectangle node{$P_{6}$} +(1.3,3.0);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5.0) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] 
{\footnotesize $P_1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(3.5,0.65) -- (3.5,6.5)node [black,midway,xshift=9pt] {\footnotesize
$P_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Remark: it's easier to use the `/pgf/decoration/raise` option instead of `xshift` and `yshift` the brace manually. _____________________________________________________________________________________________ Related: [Making Curly Braces with Tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230566/making-curly-braces-with-tikz)

Comment: @user202729 Good job completing non-working examples (NWE)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

There's a `mirror` option for the decorations which in essence turns the direction of the path around:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (-1,0) rectangle +(6,7.5);
\filldraw[thick, top color=white,bottom color=red!50!] (0.5,0) rectangle node{$N_S$} +(1.3,0.5);
\filldraw[thick, top color=white,bottom color=red!50!] (2.2,0) rectangle node{$N_L$} +(1.3,0.65);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,0.5) rectangle node{$P_{1}$} +(1.3,0.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,0.65) rectangle node{$P_{2}$} +(1.3,1.0);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,1.0) rectangle node{$P_{3}$} +(1.3,1.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,1.65) rectangle node{$P_{4}$} +(1.3,2.0);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,2.5) rectangle node{$P_{5}$} +(1.3,2.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,3.65) rectangle node{$P_{6}$} +(1.3,3.0);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5.0) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] 
{\footnotesize $P_1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt]
(3.5,0.65) -- (3.5,6.5) node [black,midway,xshift=0.8cm] {\footnotesize
$P_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know that!  I've always done this by drawing the path in the other direction.  Learn something new every day.

Comment: Thanks, Loop Space. Your comment was helpful in rotating 90 degrees.

Answer (score 44):

Another possibility is to simply flip start and end points of the brace:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[thick] (-1,0) rectangle +(6,7.5);
\filldraw[thick, top color=white,bottom color=red!50!] (0.5,0) rectangle node{$N_S$} +(1.3,0.5);
\filldraw[thick, top color=white,bottom color=red!50!] (2.2,0) rectangle node{$N_L$} +(1.3,0.65);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,0.5) rectangle node{$P_{1}$} +(1.3,0.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,0.65) rectangle node{$P_{2}$} +(1.3,1.0);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,1.0) rectangle node{$P_{3}$} +(1.3,1.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,1.65) rectangle node{$P_{4}$} +(1.3,2.0);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (0.5,2.5) rectangle node{$P_{5}$} +(1.3,2.5);
\filldraw[top color=white,bottom color=blue!50!] (2.2,3.65) rectangle node{$P_{6}$} +(1.3,3.0);
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt] (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,5.0) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm] {\footnotesize $P_1$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt] (3.5,6.5) -- (3.5,0.65) node [black,midway,xshift=9pt] {\footnotesize $P_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```