# How to use three dots and brackets with TikZ to draw Automaton state machine?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I tried to add a curly braces below all the states in order to group them, but I couldn't find a way to make it work. Furthermore, how could I draw a three dots as a state since I need to prove a theorem by induction on n. Here is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial]                (q_0)                           {$a$};
        \node[state]                        (q_1)   [right=of q_0]          {$a^2$};
        \node[state]                        (q_2)   [right=of q_1]          {$a^3$};
        \node[state,accepting]              (q_3)   [right=of q_2]          {$a^n$};    

        \path[->]
        (q_0)   edge                        node {a}            (q_1)  
        (q_1)   edge                        node {a}            (q_2) 
        (q_2)   edge                        node {...}          (q_3) 
        (q_3)   edge    [loop above]        node {a}            (q_3)
        ; %end path 
    \end{tikzpicture}   \\
\end{document}
```

This is the picture that illustrates what I meant:
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5701).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,automata,calc,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
        \node[state,initial]                (q_0)                           {$a$};
        \node[state]                        (q_1)   [right=of q_0]          {$a^2$};
        \node[state]                        (q_2)   [right=of q_1]          {$a^3$};
        \node[state,accepting]              (q_3)   [right=of q_2]          {$a^n$};    

        \path[->]
        (q_0)   edge                        node {a}            (q_1)  
        (q_1)   edge                        node {a}            (q_2) 
        (q_2)   edge                        node {...}          (q_3) 
        (q_3)   edge    [loop above]        node {a}            (q_3)
        ; %end path 
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt}, thick] ($(q_0.south west)+(-1.5,0)$)--(q_3.south east);  
    \end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know  `automata library` perhaps there is  a node for `start` to avoid `+(-1.5,0)`. I know it's possible to define `intial distance` so in this case you know the distance between start and the first node. Well, you need to read the pgfmanual about this library to customize the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah I really want to get rid of the start, but I've just used TikZ for a day. I will look it up.

Answer (score 13):

Just a little change over Altermundus' answer with \dots being an state.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=2cm,on grid,auto] 
    \node[state,initial] (q_0) {$a$};
    \node[state] (q_1) [right=of q_0] {$a^2$};
    \node[state] (q_2) [right=of q_1] {$a^3$};
      \node        (q_dots) [right=of q_2] {$\cdots$}; 
    \node[state,accepting] (q_3) [right=of q_dots] {$a^n$};    

    \path[->]
    (q_0) edge node {a} (q_1)  
    (q_1) edge node {a} (q_2) 
    (q_2) edge  node {a} (q_dots) 
    (q_dots) edge node{a} (q_3)
    (q_3) edge [loop above] node {a} (q_3)
    ; %end path 

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=10pt},yshift=0pt]
(q_0.south west) -- (q_3.south east);

\end{tikzpicture}   \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one ;) Thanks a lot. By the way, how can I add text below the bracket? Could you help?

Comment: @Chan: you can find the solution in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/draw-curly-braces-in-tikz)