# Make curly braces wrap around part of a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Essentially the same question as [Draw Curly Braces in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/draw-curly-braces-in-tikz) except that I want the brace to wrap around a circle to display an angular sector (for example 0-30 degrees). How can I do this?

---

I dont know if it is even possible, but here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw[style=thick] (0,0) circle (7);
\draw[thin,dashed] (0, 0 ) -- (100:7) ;
\draw[thin,dashed] (0, 0 ) -- (170:7) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a first version, the meeting point in the middle lokks still bad, but I'm working on it.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\cucubr}[7]{%
%origin point, circle radius, start angle, end angle, distance c-b, brace radius, brace options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpangleedge}{atan(#6/(#2+#5+#6))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpanglemid}{atan(#6/(#2+#5+2*#6))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\halfangle}{(#4-#3)/2+#3}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\innerradius}{#2+#5}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{#2+#5+#6}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\outerradius}{#2+#5+2*#6}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstmidanglestart}{mod(\halfangle-\helpanglemid+180,360)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondmidanglestart}{mod(\halfangle+\helpanglemid+180,360)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstmidanglestop}{mod(\halfangle-\helpanglemid+180,360)-90}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondmidanglestop}{mod(\halfangle+\helpanglemid+180,360)+90}%
%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (#3:\innerradius) arc (#3+270:#3+360:#6) arc (#3+\helpangleedge:\halfangle-\helpanglemid:\midradius) arc (\firstmidanglestart:\firstmidanglestop:#6);%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (#4:\innerradius) arc (#4+90:#4:#6) arc (#4-\helpangleedge:\halfangle+\helpanglemid:\midradius) arc (\secondmidanglestart:\secondmidanglestop:#6);% node[black, text width=2.5cm,draw] {mid:\firstmidanglestart, one:\firstmidanglestop, two:\secondmidanglestop, half:\halfangle};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0:4) arc (0:90:4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (90:4) arc (90:180:4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (180:4) arc (180:270:4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (270:4) arc (270:360:4) -- cycle;
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{0}{90}{0.4}{0.5}{thick,red}
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{90}{180}{0.9}{1.0}{thick,green}
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{180}{270}{0.2}{0.3}{thick,blue}
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{270}{360}{0.6}{0.6}{thick,teal}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** I got a much better variant than before, it involves more math now. While this should be correct, I still got variations, so the brace would't always close in the middle. I *think* my math is correct, and I ran into some computation deviations in TikZ: the angles computed by TikZ vary by up to 0.35 degrees from the real. While this does does not seem much, it was up to 10% of the angle, or the equivalent of 1.5 linewidths. As I found no way around, I decided to start drawing from the center. That way the brace ends meet in the middle, and I only needed to adapt one value due to deviations. Here's the final code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\cucubr}[7]{%
%origin point, circle radius, start angle, end angle, distance c-b, brace radius, brace options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpangleedge}{acos(1-pow(#6,2)/2/pow(#2+#5,2))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\turnangleedge}{90+(\helpangleedge/2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpanglemid}{acos(1-pow(#6,2)/2/pow(#2+#5+2*#6,2))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\turnanglemid}{90-(\helpanglemid/2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\halfangle}{(#4-#3)/2+#3}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{#2+#5+#6}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\outerradius}{#2+#5+1.88*#6}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstmidanglestart}{mod(\halfangle-\helpanglemid+180,360)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondmidanglestart}{mod(\halfangle+\helpanglemid+180,360)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstmidanglestop}{mod(\halfangle-\helpanglemid/2+180,360)-\turnanglemid}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondmidanglestop}{mod(\halfangle+\helpanglemid/2+180,360)++\turnanglemid}%
%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (\halfangle:\outerradius) arc (\firstmidanglestop:\firstmidanglestart:#6) arc (\halfangle-\helpanglemid:#3+\helpangleedge:\midradius) arc (#3+270+\turnangleedge+\helpangleedge/2:#3+270+\helpangleedge/2:#6) ;%
%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (\halfangle:\outerradius) arc (\secondmidanglestop:\secondmidanglestart:#6) arc (\halfangle+\helpanglemid:#4-\helpangleedge:\midradius) arc (#4+90-\turnangleedge-\helpangleedge/2:#4+90-\helpangleedge/2:#6);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (00:4) arc (0:90:4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (90:4) arc (90:180:4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (180:4) arc (180:270:4) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) -- (270:4) arc (270:360:4) -- cycle;
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{0}{90}{0.4}{0.5}{red,densely dotted}
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{90}{180}{0.9}{1.0}{thin,green}
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{180}{270}{0.2}{0.3}{ultra thick,blue,densely dashed}
\cucubr{0,0}{4}{270}{360}{0.6}{0.6}{thick,teal,-latex}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit 2:** I double and tripple checked the math, it *really, really should* be correct. So I started investigating the deviations when calculating. The TikZ manual states that the power and accuracy of it's engine are limited due to limitations of TeX. Sadly, this is the first time I ran into them. I calculated the values of the angles I needed for different values of circle radius and brace radius:

[image]

The values should decrease left to right and top down, but for small radii they don't. As this limits the accuracy achievable, I decided to choose yet another approach: starting the brace from inside and outside, and then connecting the pieces via `to[out=<degrees>,in=<degrees>]`. This looks well enough, at least if you don't choose a lage brace radius for a small circle radius.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/savenumber/.code 2 args={\global\edef#1{#2}}}

\newcommand{\cucubr}[7]{%
%origin point, circle radius, start angle, end angle, distance c-b, brace radius, brace options
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpangleedge}{acos(1-pow(#6,2)/2/pow(#2+#5,2))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\turnangleedge}{90+(\helpangleedge/2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpanglemid}{acos(1-pow(#6,2)/2/pow(#2+#5+2*#6,2))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\turnanglemid}{90-(\helpanglemid/2)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\halfangle}{(#4-#3)/2+#3}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\innerradius}{#2+#5}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\midradius}{#2+#5+#6}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\outerradius}{#2+#5+2*#6-sqrt(1/#2)*0.01}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstmidanglestart}{mod(\halfangle-\helpanglemid+180,360)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondmidanglestart}{mod(\halfangle+\helpanglemid+180,360)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\firstmidanglestop}{mod(\halfangle-\helpanglemid/2+180,360)-\turnanglemid}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\secondmidanglestop}{mod(\halfangle+\helpanglemid/2+180,360)+\turnanglemid}%
%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (\halfangle:\outerradius) arc (\firstmidanglestop:\firstmidanglestart:#6) node (A) {};%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (#3:\innerradius) arc (#3+270+\helpangleedge/2:#3+270+\turnangleedge+\helpangleedge/2:#6) node (B) {};%
%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (\halfangle:\outerradius) arc (\secondmidanglestop:\secondmidanglestart:#6) node (C) {};%
\draw[#7] (#1) ++ (#4:\innerradius) arc (#4+90-\helpangleedge/2:#4+90-\turnangleedge-\helpangleedge/2:#6) node (D) {};%
%
\draw[#7] (A.center) to[out=\firstmidanglestop+180,in=#3+90+\helpangleedge/2] (B.center);%
\draw[#7] (C.center) to[out=\secondmidanglestop-180,in=#4-90-\helpangleedge/2](D.center);%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,gray,densely dotted] (0,0) -- (20:7);
\draw[very thin,gray,densely dotted] (0,0) -- (80:7);
\draw[very thin,gray,densely dotted] (0,0) -- (150:7);
\foreach \r in {1,...,6}
{   \cucubr{0,0}{\r}{20}{80}{0.2}{0.3}{blue}
    \cucubr{0,0}{\r}{80}{150}{0.5}{0.5}{red}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the smaller braces look "staircasey", but this vanishes with higher ratios of circle radius to brace radius.

[image]

Comment: Very good effort. I write no it's impossible now I look stupid. The way you take was a possibility but I thought this way was too difficult and too complicated for something simple and flexible.

Comment: You don't look too stupid :) This solution only works exact if r<<R. As one can see at the teal and green braces, for larger brace radii the overlap is not good anymore. I will do some math and try to improve it.

Comment: Fine result ! I try `\foreach \r in {1,2,3,4,5,6}   
{\cucubr{0,0}{\r}{20}{80}{0.2}{0.3}{blue}
\cucubr{0,0}{\r}{80}{150}{0.2}{0.3}{red}}`. The result is not very good with little radius. I don't have enough time to look at my next suggestion but perhaps it's possible to adapt some code with the radius of arc or perhaps to fix some dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, robbed me of the whole day ;) Sadly it _is_ due to limited accuracy. So you might be right after all, it is not solvable _exactly_, but at least something like "close enough".

Answer (score 17):

Finally I get the next code without "big" calculus.

**Update version 2**

I added some keys like `tip angle` and find something better for the tip.

**Figure**

[image: main]

**Details**

[image: detail]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter 

\tikzset{curlybrace/.style={rounded corners=2pt,line cap=round}}%  
\pgfkeys{%
/curlybrace/.cd,%
tip angle/.code     =  \def\cb@angle{#1},
/curlybrace/.unknown/.code ={\let\searchname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                              \pgfkeysalso{\searchname/.try=#1,
                              /tikz/\searchname/.retry=#1}}}  
\def\curlybrace{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\curly@brace}{\curly@brace[]}}%

\def\curly@brace[#1]#2#3#4{% 
\pgfkeys{/curlybrace/.cd,
tip angle = 0.75}% 
\pgfqkeys{/curlybrace}{#1}% 
\ifnum 1>#4 \def\cbrd{0.05} \else \def\cbrd{0.075} \fi
\draw[/curlybrace/.cd,curlybrace,#1]  (#2:#4-\cbrd) -- (#2:#4) arc (#2:{(#2+#3)/2-\cb@angle}:#4) --({(#2+#3)/2}:#4+\cbrd) coordinate (curlybracetipn);
\draw[/curlybrace/.cd,curlybrace,#1] ({(#2+#3)/2}:#4+\cbrd) -- ({(#2+#3)/2+\cb@angle}:#4) arc ({(#2+#3)/2+\cb@angle} :#3:#4) --(#3:#4-\cbrd);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[help lines](-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\curlybrace[color=blue,thick]{30}{60}{1.2}
\curlybrace[color=blue]{30}{60}{0.6}
\curlybrace[color=blue]{30}{60}{2}    
\draw circle(1cm);

\curlybrace[color=red]{90}{160}{3} \node[red,anchor=south] at (curlybracetipn) {$70^\circ$};
\curlybrace[color=red,thin]{90}{160}{1.2}
\curlybrace[color=red,thin]{90}{160}{0.6}
\curlybrace[color=red,thin]{90}{160}{0.3} 
\curlybrace[color=red,thin]{90}{160}{2} 
\curlybrace[color=red]{90}{160}{3} 
\curlybrace[color=green!40!black,thick]{180}{360}{1.2}
\curlybrace[color=green!40!black,thick]{180}{360}{0.6}
\curlybrace[color=green!40!black,thick]{180}{360}{0.3} 
\curlybrace[color=green!40!black,ultra thick,tip angle=2]{180}{360}{3}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Todo**

It's possible to add :

1. a coordinate to place a label at the middle of the brace (do)
2. some keys with  pgfkeys  to get a better control for `rounded corners`, for the little angle that I use at the middle of the brace (0.75 degree). We can calc this angle  function of the radius.(do)
3. expression to calc some values according to the radius like `\def\cbrd{0.05}`we can avoid this with some calculus.
4. styles with pgfkeys to add arrows for example. it's easy (do)
5. to get a better junction at the middle, it would be interesting to use only one path . Actually the result is fine with line width not to big.(do with line `cap=round`)

**First idea**

It was to begin  with a simple code to get some coordinates and then to add some ornaments but finally "rounded corners" was enough.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\curlybrace}[3]{%
\draw  (#1:#3-0.1) -- (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)--(#2:#3-0.1) ; 
\draw ({(#1+#2)/2}:#3) -- ({(#1+#2)/2}:#3+0.1);}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw[help lines](-3,-3) grid (3,3);
\curlybrace{30}{60}{1.2}
\curlybrace{30}{60}{2}    
\draw circle(1cm);

\curlybrace{90}{160}{1.2}
\curlybrace{90}{160}{2}  
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to scale the curly braces.

Comment: The best answer!

Comment: Wow, very nice approach! Good to see your ego couldn't let it go ;) Definitively deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: @TomBombadil I did not want to continue to remain stupid ! :) The accepted answer is for you because you gave the first effort and I tried to find a solution because you show me the way. I did not like the idea of curly brace, it's why I started slowly.

Answer (score 8):

This is the PMB (poor man's brace) version.

It uses the arrow styles `right to reserved` and `left to reserved` from the arrow library.

The solution isn't very sophisticated as it enables one only to draw braces around `(0,0)`. (The `shift` key is already used, so an outer scope is necessary here.)

Next step would be to include this in some kind of style of `to` or `arc` which I won't follow up because we already have [Alain Matthes's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45129/16595).

### Code

```
\documentclass[
    tikz,
    border=2pt,
]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\newcommand*{\braceme}[6][]{% #1 = optional
                            % #2 = radius
                            % #3 = start angle
                            % #4 = end angle
                            % #5 = node name
                            % #6 = node content
\draw[
    shift={(#3:#2)},
    right to reversed-right to reversed,
    shorten >=-.75\pgflinewidth,
    #1
    ] (0,0)
        arc[radius=#2, start angle=#3, end angle=#3+(#4-#3)/2] node[rotate=#3+(#4-#3)/2-90,above=2pt] (#5) {#6};
\draw[
    shift={({#3+(#4-#3)/2}:#2)},
    left to reversed-left to reversed,
    shorten <=-.75\pgflinewidth,
    #1
    ] (0,0)
        arc[radius=#2, start angle=#3+(#4-#3)/2, end angle=#4];
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
\draw[style=thick] (0,0) circle (7);
\draw[thin,dashed] (0, 0 ) -- (100:7) ;
\draw[thin,dashed] (0, 0 ) -- (170:7) ;
\braceme[thick]{7.5}{100}{170}{br1}{Hi!}
\braceme[thick]{8}{180}{390}{br2}{Test?}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
  \draw (0,0) -- (30:1);
  \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt,mirror,raise=4pt}] (1,0) -- (30:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, though this wasnt what I had in mind. A lienar brace wont neatly cover for example, 60 degrees.

Comment: I think the answer is no with tikz. Why not use a classic method with an arc ?

Comment: @Altermundus -- if you really want to, you can always remove a comment that you've written.  if you mouse over your comment, there's a little "x" at the end that you can click on to do the job.  (speaking from lots of practice.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I  think it's  impossible to transform a linear brace to a curved(curly) brace (with tikz). But I need to keep my comment to know why I'm stupid _ Tikz can draw every vector object with obstinacy, talent and work_. Tom makes a great effort to get a fine result. Perhaps it's possible to improve a little bit the code.