# Bending a curly brace around a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make curly braces wrap around part of a circle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44723/make-curly-braces-wrap-around-part-of-a-circle)

I am trying to put a curly brace into a `Tikz` picture, more specifically, to bend that curly brace along a circular path, but not all the way around the circle. This is my code to get the picture without the brace.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{snnode/.style={circle,draw=black,inner sep=.55pt,fill}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (x) at (0,0);
\draw (0,0) circle (.5);
\foreach \i in {110,90,80,10} {
  \node[snnode] (1a\i) at ($(x)+(\i:.8)$) {};}
\foreach \i in {100,70} {
  \node[snnode] (1a\i) at ($(x)+(\i:.2)$) {};}
\foreach \i in {110,100,90,80,70,10} {
  \node[snnode] (a\i) at ($(x)+(\i:.5)$) {};
  \draw (a\i) to (1a\i);}
\foreach \i in {50,40,30} {\node (z) at ($(x)+(\i:.7)$) {$\cdot$};}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That gives me the picture on the left, but I want something like the picture on the right.

[image] [image]

In the picture I've shown the nib of the brace off center, but I would like for it to be in the middle of the arced brace. The shape of the brace should preferably be the standard shape of the curly brace in math mode, i.e. `\{`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please confirm if your question is a duplicate of @percusse's link; if not, please say how your question is different :)

Comment: @cmhughes YES exactly the same! I was looking for "bend" and "arced" instead of "wrap." Thanks.