# Underbracing on a set of points in a plot with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, grouping

I have two sets of points graphed in the same plot. I want to mark them grouped with an under- or overbrazing with a large curly bracket, as I have illustrated by hand here:

[image]

I am looking for the same type of brazing as in mathematical formatting with $$\underbrace{a+b+c}_n$$:

[image]

A [working code for testing](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/58e4e28a54b8ca05149425b0) is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{height=7cm, width=8.5cm}

\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    hide x axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=600,ymax=1000
]
\addplot[only marks,orange] coordinates {
    (1,700)
    (2,700)
    (3,700)
    (4,700)
    (5,700)
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    hide x axis,
    hide y axis,
    ymin=600,ymax=1000,
    xmin=0, xmax=8
]
\addplot[only marks,blue] coordinates {
    (6,900)
    (7,900)
};
\node at (axis cs:1, 725) {1};
\node at (axis cs:2, 725) {2};
\node at (axis cs:3, 725) {3};
\node at (axis cs:4, 725) {4};
\node at (axis cs:5, 725) {5};
\node at (axis cs:6, 925) {6};
\node at (axis cs:7, 925) {7};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As a remark, why does this tex.SE site not render math formatting with $$...$$?

Comment: because we are more interested in the code https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths

Comment: You could use [Using Tikz in a figure, can I draw braces between nodes and control spacing between brace ends and the nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144917/124842). I think its a duplicat, you need only some modifications.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `decorations={brace}` to create a brace with `tikz` between two points.

I defined the required nodes with `A`, `B` etc. to reuse the positions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{height=7cm, width=8.5cm}

\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    hide x axis,
    xmin=0, xmax=8,
    ymin=600,ymax=1000
]
\addplot[only marks,orange] coordinates {
    (1,700)
    (2,700)
    (3,700)
    (4,700)
    (5,700)
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    hide x axis,
    hide y axis,
    ymin=600,ymax=1000,
    xmin=0, xmax=8
]
\addplot[only marks,blue] coordinates {
    (6,900)
    (7,900)
};
\node (A) at (axis cs:1, 725) {1};
\node at (axis cs:2, 725) {2};
\node at (axis cs:3, 725) {3};
\node at (axis cs:4, 725) {4};
\node (B) at (axis cs:5, 725) {5};
\node (C) at (axis cs:6, 925) {6};
\node (D) at (axis cs:7, 925) {7};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,mirror,raise=6mm}]
(A.west) -- (B.east) node [black,midway, below, yshift=-10mm] {a};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=6mm}]
(C.west) -- (D.east) node [black,midway, below, yshift=-10mm] {b};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]