# Help reproducing a tikzpicture image with foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm still getting started with tikzpicture. Here's the result I want to obtain with it in a automatically-fancy code

[image: wannabe]

This is what I'm up to though. I can't even get past this:

[image: result]

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass[standalone]
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\vectorcell[5]   {\draw[fill=#3] (#5) rectangle +(#1,#2);
                       \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ($(#5)+({0.5*#1},{0.5*#2})$) {#4};
                       \node[font=\sffamily] at ($(#5)+({0.5*#1+5},{0.5*#2})$) {\texttt{threadIdx.x = }#4};
                      }
\newcommand\cell[1]       {\vectorcell{1}{1}{gray!30}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]%
\foreach \j in {0,1,2}%souldn't I remove the following semicolon?
    \node[font=\sffamily] at (12,4.1*\j+1.0) {\texttt{blockIdx.x = }\j};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}%
        \cell{\i}{0,1.1*\i+0.5};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

My issue is **I can't put the second `foreach` to work**: I supposed it's the semicolon stated above. If I remove it the code doesn't compile, while if I keep it I only get one column of threads, so it sure isn't.

My questions are two:

- How can I have tikz create `one column` of `threadIdx.x` `per`blockIdx.x`index`?
- How can I `rotate then the`blockIdx.x`label`?

On a side note, what about the curly braces? I believe with the answers above I can do it myself though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\foreach` can be used as `\foreach \i in {0,1,2} { \foo{\i} }`, where the last brace gives the scope of what is repeated for each iteration of `\i`.  Using this we can rewrite

```
\foreach \j in {0,1,2}%souldn't I remove the following semicolon?
    \node[font=\sffamily] at (12,4.1*\j+1.0) {\texttt{blockIdx.x = }\j};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}%
        \cell{\i}{0,1.1*\i+0.5};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

as

```
\foreach \j in {0,1,2} {
    \node[font=\sffamily] at (12,4.1*\j+1.0) {\texttt{blockIdx.x = }\j};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
        \cell{\i}{0,1.1*\i+0.5};
    }
}
```

where now the second loop runs for each value of `\j`, although right now `\cell{\i}{0,1.1*\i+0.5};` will just print the same thing in the same place three times, we can tell it to position the cells according to the value of `\j` using `\cell{\i}{0,4.1*\j+1.1*\i+0.5};`.

At this point we have

[image]

so we can see that the `\foreach` parts of the code are running as intended (although spacing needs a bit of adjustment).

Using [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20887/106162) to [Draw Curly Braces in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20885/106162) we can then add the braces along with passing the `rotate=-90` option to the node to get close to the intended diagram.

[image]

(I misread the diagram when doing this part so there's a correction added below)

Finally though the "thread" labels are only following the `\i` index.  In order to do the necessary maths we need to change `\vectorcell` replacing `#4` in the definition with `\pgfmathparse{int(#4)}\pgfmathresult` will give the integer value of the first argument given to `\cell` so we can now do maths there.  Finally to get ascending numbers as we go down, the easiest way (one could re-work some of the code instead...) is simply to pass `[yshift=-1]` as an option to the `tikzpicture` environment (this necessitates removal of the `mirror` option passed to the braces).

Thus we have

[image]

Produced from

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}

\newcommand\vectorcell[5]{\draw[fill=#3] (#5) rectangle +(#1,#2);
                       \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ($(#5)+({0.5*#1},{0.5*#2})$) {\pgfmathparse{int(#4)}\pgfmathresult};
                       \node[font=\sffamily] at ($(#5)+({0.5*#1+5},{0.5*#2})$) {\texttt{threadIdx.x = }\pgfmathparse{int(#4)}\pgfmathresult};
                      }
\newcommand\cell[2]{\vectorcell{1}{1}{gray!30}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,yscale=-1]
\foreach \j in {0,1,2}{
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt] (8.5,6*\j+0.5) -- (8.5,6*\j+4.8) node [black,midway,xshift=0.8cm,rotate=-90] {\texttt{blockIdx.x = }\j};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
        \cell{\i+4*\j}{0,6*\j+1.1*\i+0.5};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(More of an aside: I don't understand why you have `\newcommand\cell[1]{\vectorcell{1}{1}{gray!30}{#1}}` when `\vectorcell` takes five mandatory arguments, `\newcommand\cell[2]{\vectorcell{1}{1}{gray!30}{#1}{#2}}` makes more sense to me, so I've changed to that above.)

---

Ok, so the labelling grey blocks should follow `4*\j+\i` while the thread numbers should only follow `\i`.  Given the `\cell` macro is only called once, probably the simplest way for now is to just "unpack" it and place it all directly in the `foreach` macros as

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,yscale=-1]
\foreach \j in {0,1,2}{
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=4pt},yshift=0pt] (8.5,6*\j+0.5) -- (8.5,6*\j+4.8) node [black,midway,xshift=0.8cm,rotate=-90] {\texttt{blockIdx.x = }\j};
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3}{
        \draw[fill=gray!30] (0,6*\j+1.1*\i+0.5) rectangle +(1,1);
        \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries] at ($(0,6*\j+1.1*\i+0.5)+(0.5,0.5)$) {\pgfmathparse{int(4*\j+\i)}\pgfmathresult};
        \node[font=\sffamily] at ($(0,6*\j+1.1*\i+0.5)+(5.5,0.5)$) {\texttt{threadIdx.x = }\pgfmathparse{int(\i)}\pgfmathresult};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

where `\i` alone is used to label the threads and `4*\j+\i` is used for the blocks.

One could even avoid the calculation of where to place the number inside the box by using

```
\draw[fill=gray!30] (0,6*\j+1.1*\i+0.5) rectangle +(1,1)
    node [midway, font=\sffamily\bfseries] {\pgfmathparse{int(4*\j+\i)}\pgfmathresult};
```

to automatically center the node within the rectangle which has just been drawn.

Perhaps even that node could be labelled itself so that the `threadIdx.x =` node is placed relative to that, i.e.

```
\draw[fill=gray!30] (0,6*\j+1.1*\i+0.5) rectangle +(1,1)
    node (boxnumber-\i-\j) [midway, font=\sffamily\bfseries] {\pgfmathparse{int(4*\j+\i)}\pgfmathresult};
\node[font=\sffamily] at ($(boxnumber-\i-\j)+(5,0)$) {\texttt{threadIdx.x = }\pgfmathparse{int(\i)}\pgfmathresult};
```

Not that these are necessary for it to work, or even that much nicer to look at.

However, I have now removed the `\newcommand`s that you had earlier, maybe wrapping the drawing steps up in a macro is what you want.  I think using a two-macro `\cell` command to pass a coordinate and one value from the counters is a non-starter, both need to be input separately (or two linearly-independent combinations at least).  So as a basic we need

```
\newcommand{\thread}[3]{
    \draw[fill=gray!30] (#3) rectangle +(1,1)
        node (boxnumber-#1) [midway, font=\sffamily\bfseries] {\pgfmathparse{int(#1)}\pgfmathresult};
    \node[font=\sffamily] at ($(boxnumber-#1)+(5,0)$) {\texttt{threadIdx.x = }\pgfmathparse{int(#2)}\pgfmathresult};
}
```

If there is a need to change the box size or colour, this could be done as additional arguments (possibly optional, or even key-val).  I would suggest add the box size as a single argument expecting two values separated by a comma - namely a coordinate.

```
\newcommand{\thread}[5][gray!30]{
    \draw[fill=#1] (#5) rectangle +(#2)
        node (boxnumber-#3) [midway, font=\sffamily\bfseries] {\pgfmathparse{int(#3)}\pgfmathresult};
    \node[font=\sffamily] at ($(boxnumber-#3)+(5,0)$) {\texttt{threadIdx.x = }\pgfmathparse{int(#4)}\pgfmathresult};
}
```

Perhaps grouping the `blockIdx` label and the inner `foreach` into a single command might be useful, given there's no use-case given, I'll stop suggesting things with ever more tenuous usefulness.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tikz is so powerful yet so difficult for beginners

Comment: Hang on, I noticed just now: the `threadIdx.x` index must run from 0 to 4 within all of the braces, it need not to be the same as the cells

Comment: @Eugenio misread the diagram, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure where you are heading. So far your application doesn't look like a typical use case for `tikz`, except maybe for the grey box. Here is another way to achieve what you show, to give you some ideas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\boxed[1]% enclose #1 in a grey box
   {\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]
      \node[draw,fill=gray!30,inner sep=1pt,minimum width=1.4em,minimum height=2ex]
        (X){\scriptsize\bfseries\sffamily#1};%
   }
\newcommand\threadIdx[2]% #1 = index of block, #2 = offset
   {\pgfmathparse{#1*4+#2}%
    \let\tmp\pgfmathresult
    \boxed{\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tmp}}\quad
    \texttt{threadIdx.x = }{\textsf{#2}}%
   }
\newcommand\threadIdxs[1]% #1 = index of block
   {$\left.
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    \threadIdx{#1}{0}\\
    \threadIdx{#1}{1}\\
    \threadIdx{#1}{2}\\
    \threadIdx{#1}{3}
    \end{tabular}
    \right\}
    \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\scriptsize\texttt{blockIdx.x = }{\textsf{#1}}}
    $%
   }
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,1,2} {\threadIdxs{\i}\medskip\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out; your answer is perfectly clear, the thing is I want to get used to tikz, I feel like it will be useful to me in the following years. Thx anyway

Answer (score 2):

- two `foreach` loops: outer for *blockIdx* groups, inner for *threadIdx* elements
- blocks, numbered from 0 to 11 (or more, if it is required) are defined as nodes
- for placing of nodes is used `chains` package, consequently no nodes' positions calculations
- for braces, that it appearance is more fancy, is used library `calligraphy`

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains, decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 11mm,
  start chain = going below,
  lbox/.style = {font=\normalsize\ttfamily, sloped},%labels style
   box/.style = {draw, fill=gray!30, minimum size=7mm, font=\large\sffamily, 
                 label={[lbox,xshift=7mm]right:threadIdx.x = \j},
                 on chain}
                    ]
\foreach \i [count=\ii from 0] in {0,4,8}% <-- outer loop, determine blockIdx
{
    \foreach \j [count=\k from \i] in {0,1,2,3}% <-- inner loop, determine threadIdx
{
\ifnum\j=0 \node (n\j) [box,yshift=-3mm] {\k}% <-- for separating blockIdx
    \else
           \node (n\j) [box] {\k}
\fi;
}
\draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                pre=moveto, pre length=1pt, post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                raise=42mm},
                draw, thick, pen colour={red}]
      (n0.north) -- node[lbox,above=44mm] {blockIdx.x = \ii} (n3.south);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]