# tikz: Creating a Simple Diagram With Lines, Dots and Annotations

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was wondering how can I draw the following graph in LaTeX for a beamer slide. [image]

I have tried with the following code. However, I don't know how to get the dots for the lines. How can I include them?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, transform shape]
%\draw[step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,3);
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0) ; 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3) ; 
\draw[-] (1,2) -- (3,1.5); 
\draw[dotted] (1,1) -- (3,0.5); 
\draw[-] (1,1) -- (3,1.25);
\draw[->] (2.5,2.5) -- (2.15,1.8);
\draw[->] (1.6,1.5) -- (2,1.25); 
\draw[->] (1.5,0.5) -- (2,0.65); 
\draw[decoration={brace},decorate]
(3.1,1.25) -- node[right] {{\tiny Treatment Effect}} (3.1,0.5);
\node at (4,-0.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{Time}};
\node at (-0.35,3.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{Employment}};
\node at (-0.35,3) {\scriptsize\textbf{Rate}};
\node at (1,-0.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{Before}};
\node at (3,-0.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{After}};
\node at (3,2.75) {\tiny\textbf{employment trend}};
\node at (3,2.6) {\tiny\textbf{in control state}};
\node at (0.85,1.6) {\tiny\textbf{employment trend}};
\node at (0.85,1.45) {\tiny\textbf{in treatment state}};
\node at (0.85,0.5) {\tiny\textbf{counterfactual}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Your label `tikz-pgf` actually reflects that you suspect how. Tried it?

Comment: @c.p. I just updated the question with my code.

Comment: Check the `dashed` or `dotted` options to `\draw`. For the brackets, see for example this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20887/3929, they are usually referred to as *braces*, so searching for `tikz braces` makes it easy to find. A brace in this context is a decoration and you will just need to define the two end points.

Comment: @daleif Nice definition of `brace` :)

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I just updated my code again. I inserted the braces and the dotted line :)  Do you know how can I insert the dots (ending points) in the lines, as in the image.

Comment: Have a look at the `pgf` manual and look for `16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips`. Ther is the`circle` option for example.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks, I will look at it.

Comment: Either as Manuel mentions, or draw them manually `\fill (coord) circle (radius);` This is also why I often predefine the points for easier reuse, see `\coordinate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9, transform shape]
%\draw[step=0.5cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (4,3);
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0) ; 
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3) ; 
\draw[-] (1,2) -- (3,1.5); 
\draw[dotted] (1,1) -- (3,0.5); 
\draw[-] (1,1) -- (3,1.25);
\draw[->] (2.5,2.5) -- (2.15,1.8);
\draw[->] (1.6,1.5) -- (2,1.25); 
\draw[->] (1.5,0.5) -- (2,0.65); 
\draw[-] (1,0.05) -- (1,-0.05);
\draw[-] (3,0.05) -- (3,-0.05);
\draw[decoration={brace},decorate]
(3.1,1.25) -- node[right] {{\tiny Treatment Effect}} (3.1,0.5);
\node at (4,-0.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{Time}};
\node at (-0.35,3.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{Employment}};
\node at (-0.35,3) {\scriptsize\textbf{Rate}};
\node at (1,-0.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{Before}};
\node at (3,-0.25) {\scriptsize\textbf{After}};
\node at (3,2.75) {\tiny\textbf{employment trend}};
\node at (3,2.6) {\tiny\textbf{in control state}};
\node at (0.85,1.6) {\tiny\textbf{employment trend}};
\node at (0.85,1.45) {\tiny\textbf{in treatment state}};
\node at (0.85,0.5) {\tiny\textbf{counterfactual}};
\fill (1,1) circle[radius=1pt];
\fill (3,0.5) circle[radius=1pt]; 
\fill (3,1.5) circle[radius=1pt]; 
\fill (3,1.25) circle[radius=1pt]; 
\fill (1,2) circle[radius=1pt]; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```