# Braces around a tikz node (for example: "{text}" instead of just "text")

Tags: tikz-pgf

I did the following drawing on Tikz:

[image]

Its MWE is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[text width=2.65cm,text centered] (R) at (-3,0) {Radical ideals of $A$};
\node[text width=2.8cm, text centered] (C) at (3,0) {Closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$};
\draw[->,transform canvas={yshift=0.15cm}] (R) -- (C) node[midway,above]{$V(\cdot)$};
\draw[<-,transform canvas={yshift=-0.15cm}] (R) -- (C) node[midway,below]{$I(\cdot)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It looks great but I would like to have curly braces around the nodes as if they were sets (in the mathematical sense) and I would like for the arrows to be a little bigger (just like the function arrows $\to$).

How could I do it?

Comment: `\node {\{ text \}};`?  For bigger braces you can use a decoration, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20885/ By "bigger", do you mean just the arrow tips? With the tips from the `arrows.meta` library you can set the size, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161238/

Comment: Since my nodes have two lines of text, when I use your first idea I obtain the left brace on the first line and the right one on the second line, which is not what I want. I want the braces to span both lines. I also tried to use a decoration but failed to do what I described. I'll see the post about the arrows.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify what you were after (though in hindsight perhaps I should have understood what you wanted ..) Decorations can do it. By the way, it's always nicer if you make complete examples, particularly when using non-standard commands or packages/libraries. Granted, there doesn't seem to be anything relevant to the question about `\Spec`, but the general point stands.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code. Could you say a little more about how I could use decorations to do it? I already tried and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped things in styles in the code below, but that is not required.

The reason there is so much air between node text and braces is the `text width` of the nodes, that can be modified in various ways, for example  by using `\node[align=center] (R) at (-3,0) {Radical\\ideals of $A$};` instead, then the node becomes only as wide as the longest line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  Brace/.style={
     thick,
     decoration={ % define decoration
        brace,
        amplitude=5pt % height of curl
        },
     decorate % activate decoration
  },
  FuncArrow/.style={ % style for the lines
    -{To[length=3pt]}, % add arrow tip
    shorten >=8pt, shorten <=8pt % shorten the lines a bit so they don't crash with the braces
    }
]
 
\node[text width=2.65cm,text centered] (R) at (-3,0) {Radical ideals of $A$};
\node[text width=2.8cm, text centered] (C) at (3,0) {Closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} A$};

% modified the style here, and swapped the drawing coordinate order of the second one
\draw[FuncArrow,transform canvas={yshift=0.15cm}] (R) -- (C) node[midway,above]{$V(\cdot)$};
\draw[FuncArrow,transform canvas={yshift=-0.15cm}] (C) -- (R) node[midway,below]{$I(\cdot)$};


\foreach \nodename in {R,C} { % draw braces for both nodes
% the order of the coordinates matter, one is drawn from north to south, the other from south to north
% (there is a mirror option for the brace decoration, but that would need two different decorations I think)
\draw [Brace] (\nodename.north east) -- (\nodename.south east);
\draw [Brace] (\nodename.south west) -- (\nodename.north west);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

add to your preamble

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
```

and at the end of your code before endtikzpicture add

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror,raise=4pt},xshift=10pt,line 
    width=2pt]
    (3.5,-0.65) -- (3.5,0.65);
    \draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,raise=4pt},xshift=10pt,line 
    width=2pt]
    (-4,-0.65) -- (-4,0.65);
```

[image]